create column based on another column value in the same dataframe
I have a dataframe, that looks like:



Question
Answer




1
Category1


1
Category1


1
Not Important


2
Category2


2
Category2


2
Very Important



My goal is to create another column 'Category' in the dataframe which fetches the value of the category from the answer column
The resulting dataframe:



Question
Answer
Category




1
Category1
Category1


1
Category1
Category1


1
Not Important
Category1


2
Category2
Category2


2
Category2
Category2


2
Very Important
Category2




What determines the category an answer belongs to? is it based off of the question number?

You need to have another data frame to translate Answer to Category covering all cases. Otherwise there is no mapping between Not important or Very Important   and their Category. Once you have it pandas.merge will do the job
